# Score Transform, Naive Bayes

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, naivebayes

I am using Naive Bayes in MATLAB R2015a.

I can not understand `ScoreTransform`. Which is the main goal of `ScoreTransform`? How can I see the scores after and before the `ScoreTransform`?

Comment: It's just a function that is applied to the score of your classes to make it into a distribution. The choice is usually based on what data your are modelling, and thus you can choose a ScoreTransform function that will best describe the relationship of your data. To see what it looks like, simply use `'none'` to remove its effect and look at your class scores and then apply something like `'logit'` to view a logarithmic distribution of your score for your classes

Comment: Many thanks for your comment.